# How to open a long/short order based on supertrend strategy and time?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am a newbie to Pine and trying to backtest.

I want to write a script where I want to buy/sell at 3:00PM based on supertrend strategy.

For example, if supertrend suggests sell, it should trigger a sell order with SL/TGT exact at 3PM only. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'll let you tweak the below for your SL/TGT logic
You need to use the **hour** built-in variable

```
//@version=5

// # ========================================================================= #
// #                   |   Strategy  |
// # ========================================================================= #

SystemName = "Supertrend Strategy"
// These values are used both in the strategy() header and in the script's relevant inputs as default values so they match.
// Unless these values match in the script's Inputs and the TV backtesting Properties, results between them cannot be compared.
InitCapital = 1000000
InitPosition = 2
InitCommission = 0.075
InitPyramidMax = 1
CalcOnorderFills = false
ProcessOrdersOnClose = true
CalcOnEveryTick = false
//CloseEntriesRule = "ANY"

strategy(title=SystemName, shorttitle=SystemName, 
 overlay=true, pyramiding=InitPyramidMax, initial_capital=InitCapital, default_qty_type=strategy.fixed, process_orders_on_close=ProcessOrdersOnClose,
 default_qty_value=InitPosition, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=InitCommission, calc_on_order_fills=CalcOnorderFills, 
 calc_on_every_tick=CalcOnEveryTick, 
 precision=6, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500)

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(3, 10)
plot(direction < 0 ? supertrend : na, "Up direction", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(direction > 0 ? supertrend : na, "Down direction", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

bull = direction < 0 and hour == 15
bear = direction > 0 and hour == 15

if bull
   strategy.entry(id = "Long", direction =  strategy.long, comment = "Long")

else if bear
   strategy.entry(id = "Short", direction =  strategy.short, comment = "Short")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using this in trading View. I wanted to know if we can place real automated orders using the strategy in the mt4 account?

Comment: Also, in the strategy, I added strategy.exit also based on profit/loss points. However, it sometimes exits the order next day without hitting any of it.